# Permission denied while doplying Tomcat 8 webapp on Amaon EC2

Tags: 14.04, java, amazon-ec2, tomcat

I can't find how I can get write and read permission into the tomcat folder.

I followed [DigitalOcean's tutorial on setting up Tomcat](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04). The only thing I did different is that I used Java 8 instead of 7, but I don't think that this is causing the issue.

When I log into the tomcat web application manager and upload the war I get following error:

> FAIL - Deploy Upload Failed, Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/webapps/SimpleServlet.war (Permission denied)

When I use Filezilla to connect to EC2 and I want to drop the file into webapps folder:

> Error:    /opt/tomcat/webapps/SimpleServlet.war: open for write: permission denied
>   Error:    File transfer failed

The output of `ls -la /opt/tomcat/webapps` is:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Nov 20 09:19 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Nov 28 16:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Nov 28 16:34 docs
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Nov 28 16:34 examples
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Nov 28 16:34 host-manager
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Nov 28 16:34 manager
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov 28 16:34 ROOT
```

but this is the folder structure that can be seen in FileZilla

[image: Image filezilla ec2 structure]

On the tutorial I followed this step:

> Then create a new tomcat user. We'll make this user a member of the tomcat group, with a home directory of /opt/tomcat (where we will install Tomcat), and with a shell of /bin/false (so nobody can log into the account):

```
sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
```

Could this be the problem?

Comment: What's the output of `ls -la /opt/tomat/webapps`?

Comment: @JensErat thanks for responding, i updated my question.

Comment: I had a typo in the comment. Please try again with `ls -la /opt/tomcat/webapps` (`tomcat` instead of `tomat`).

Comment: I'm sorry @JensErat i did't notice the typo either. I have put the output into the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/opt/tomcat` is declared to be the home directory of the `tomcat` user, but belongs to the `root` user (with the `tomcat` user not having write permissions).

Scrubbing the tutorial, especially the permissions section, I have mixed feelings towards the quality of the tutorial. It speaks about "giv[ing] the tomcat user write access to the conf directory" while changing the folder's permissions. Not having write permissions for the web application server's user to the software ran seems reasonable for production use (an attacker exploiting the tomcat process will not be able to modify software), this will also prevent you from deploying applications from withing the tomcat web application manager.

I'd go for setting up `tomcat` as the `webapps` group:

```
chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

and when you need to deploy new applications, add write permissions for that group:

```
chmod -R g+w /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

which you remove again after deployment:

```
chmod -R g-w /opt/tomcat/webapps
```

(you will need to run those commands with super user privileges, so prefix `sudo` as needed). This would also fit the [Tomcat Security Considerations HowTo](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html#Non-Tomcat%20settings).

Comment: Thanks for this. I would up vote your question but i don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: If you really feel like upvoting -- you're just two reputation points away from that privilege, which is for example earned by [improving a single other user's post by an edit](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Finally enough reputation to up vote your question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To give the permissions

ex. for Tomcat8

$ cd  /var/lib
$ ls -ld tomcat8

$ sudo  chmod  -R  o+w   tomcat8/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).